# Pandas converting date with string in

Tags: python, csv, pandas, datetime, numpy

I'm starting with python and pandas and matplotlib. I'm working with data with over million entries. I'm trying to change the date format. In CSV file date format is 23-JUN-11. I will like to use dates in future to plot amount of donation for each candidate. How to convert the date format to a readable format for pandas?

[Here is the link to cut file 149 entries](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5QNBpFZ7Ie2U3ExN3ZCNWIyeFE/view?usp=sharing)

## My code:

```
%matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

## First candidate

```
reader_bachmann = pd.read_csv('P00000001-ALL.csv' ,converters={'cand_id': lambda x: str(x)[1:]},parse_dates=True, squeeze=True, low_memory=False, nrows=411 )

date_frame = pd.DataFrame(reader_bachmann, columns = ['contb_receipt_dt'])
```

## Data slice

```
  s = date_frame.iloc[:,0]
    date_slice = pd.Series([s])
    date_strip = date_slice.str.replace('JUN','6')
```

## Trying to convert to new date format

```
 date = pd.to_datetime(s, format='%d%b%Y')
    print(date_slice)
```

## Here is the error message

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '05-JUL-11'
```

Comment: Please show an example of the date - as it is in the csv

Comment: @GiantsLoveDeathMetal Column name is contb_receipt_dt and date format is 6/20/2011

Comment: But pandas when I print array see it as date format 23-JUN-11

Comment: Can you please post a snippet of the CSV, 151MB kinda big. just a hundred rows is good enough to work on this question yeah?

Comment: @JimFactor I posted a new link with a smaller version of the file 149 entries.

Comment: For the sake of the completeness of the question I would recommend that you post a snippet of your data instead of a link to them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative you can use **dateutil.parser** to parse dates containing string directly, I have created a random dataframe for demo.

```
l = [] 
for i in range(100):
    l.append('23-JUN-11') 
B = pd.DataFrame({'Date':l})
```

Now, Let's import **dateutil.parser** and apply it on our date column

```
import dateutil.parser
B['Date2'] = B['Date'].apply(lambda x : dateutil.parser.parse(x))
B.head()
Out[106]: 
    Date      Date2
0  23-JUN-11 2011-06-23
1  23-JUN-11 2011-06-23
2  23-JUN-11 2011-06-23
3  23-JUN-11 2011-06-23
4  23-JUN-11 2011-06-23
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to use a different date format string:

```
format='%d-%b-%y'
```

**Why?**

The error message gives a clue as to what is wrong:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '05-JUL-11'

The [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) controls the conversion, and is currently:

```
format='%d%b%Y'
```

And the fields needed are:

```
%y - year without a century (range 00 to 99)
%b - abbreviated month name
%d - day of the month (01 to 31)
```

What is missing is the `-` that are separating the field in your data string, and the `y` for a two digit year instead of the current `Y` for a four digit year.